# Quarkus : How to disable/mock Vault for unit testing

Tags: junit, quarkus, vault

I'm currently facing an issue with Quarkus and Vault.

When I launch JUnit tests, Vault trying to start and it failed because Vault configuration is not setup to run locally.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:912)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.getSecretConfig(VaultConfigSource.java:78)
at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.getValue(VaultConfigSource.java:59)
```

My question is, is there a way to disable Vault during Junit tests on Quarkus like on SpringBoot (with property) ? Or create Vault Mock which can be used locally ?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can prefix all your vault configuration directives by "%prod." and inject values retrieved from vault in prod profile in your test configuration file.

In src/main/resources/application.properties

```
# Secrets retrieved via vault server
## vault server
%prod.quarkus.vault.url=https://your-vault-server
%prod.quarkus.vault.kv-secret-engine-version=2
%prod.quarkus.vault.kv-secret-engine-mount-path=secret
## vault authentication using role-id et role-secret-id (read from pod env)
%prod.quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.role-id=${ROLE_ID}
%prod.quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id=${ROLE_SECRET_ID}
## paths within the kv secret engine where are located the vault secrets to read
%prod.quarkus.vault.secret-config-kv-path=your-secret-path/SECRET
%prod.quarkus.vault.renew-grace-period=60
```

In src/test/resources/application.properties

```
SECRET=what-you-want
```

Hope this helps